# Changing as.Date function to output to a data frame instead of converting to NAs

Tags: r, substring, rbind

I want the `as.Date` function to `rbind` any values that do not match the given format (dateFormat below) onto a blank data frame. Currently, it converts them all to `NA`. We don't want it converted at all just output to the data frame. Does anyone know how to short circuit the `as.Date` function at that point?

```
dataValues = data.frame(id = c("a1", "a2", "a4", "a5", "a6","a7", "a8", "a9", "a10",  "a11", "a12","a13", "a14", "a15", "a16", "a17"),
                        value1 = c('10/3/2012', '13/4/2012', NA, '0', '1/2/2012', '2/30/2013',
                        '2/4/2012', "N/A", 'No Data', '5-6-2012', '2/5/2012',
                        'Not Applicable', '5/8/2013', '2/5/2014', '6/9/2010', '5/4/2014'),
                        stringsAsFactors =  FALSE)
dateFormat = "%m/%d/%Y"
dates = toString(dataValues[,2])
tempSplit = unlist(strsplit(dates,","))            
#If it encounters anything that is not valid for the format
#such as out of range or incorrect format it will change the value
#to NA in the data frame. 
dates = as.data.frame(as.Date(tempSplit, dateFormat))
names(dates) = c("Date")
```

Comment: why not take the values in the original data frame for which the dates data frame is NA. dtaValues[is.na(dates), ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `split` to separate the valid and invalid dates:

```
split(dataValues,is.na(as.Date(dataValues$value1,dateFormat)))
$`FALSE`
    id    value1
1   a1 10/3/2012
5   a6  1/2/2012
7   a8  2/4/2012
11 a12  2/5/2012
13 a14  5/8/2013
14 a15  2/5/2014
15 a16  6/9/2010
16 a17  5/4/2014

$`TRUE`
    id         value1
2   a2      13/4/2012
3   a4           <NA>
4   a5              0
6   a7      2/30/2013
8   a9            N/A
9  a10        No Data
10 a11       5-6-2012
12 a13 Not Applicable
```

Comment: That does provide exactly what I needed.